# How can we compute and simulate a routing/congestion game?

Tags: game-theory, simulations

As the question suggests, are the standard ways to compute/simulate a routing game?

For example, if we have a typical routing game with 10 players where each aims to minimize their utility by choosing a path that connects their origin-destination pair, then how can we compute the Nash equilibrium (the best paths for each player)?

So far on my own search, I have found NashPy for normal-form games but doesn't seem to support routing games.

I'd appreciate any help on this. Thank you.